# Transfer Data from a Adaptive SQL Anywhere version 7 32 bit database to an MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, sqlanywhere

I need some help! I'm trying transer data every morning from the main database to a second one. The data are stored in a Adaptive SQL Anywhere version 7 DB 32 bit and I want to store the datas of two tables in a MYSQL db which should make every morning a data actualisation and stores new datas from the previous day. I'm new and have some questions.

Does the second db(MYSQL) need the same bit version like the productive db (32bit) or can i use a 64 bit MYSQl db?

I made two selects and the result of these should be executed(schedueled) every morning and the result should be stored in the second db (mysql).

What do I need to realize my little project?

And how can I realize the automatic datatransfeir?

Would be glad for some help and tips.

Thanks in advance.

Greetings little student

Comment: On a Linux or similar machine it would sound like a straightforward scripting task. Use `cron` to trigger a `bash` script that extracts the data from the first database and converts it (if neccessary) into SQL insert syntax, and sends that to the second database. It is also possible that you didn't intend to ask quite so broad a question.

Comment: hello Mark Roberts, my question is so broad cause i have never done something like this before and I have no clue what I have to do. So how can i specify my question when I dont know how? But now I got some information from you to make some research. Thank you very much. Is it only possible on linux? Does it matter if my operating system is win 10 32 bit or 64 bit? Cause of the different versions of my databases?

Comment: And sorry. I forgot to say that the operating system where the mysql db is running is win 10 64 bit. and there should be executed the script which extracts the data from the 32 bit db and insert it into the mysql 64 bit both dbs are in the same network but not on the same server.

Comment: Hi LittelStudent, I am a stranger to Windows and can't therefore be of any help. It is possible to install typical Linux-Tools on Windows, but I suppose Windows people would find that a kinky approach. There must be a `cron` replacement for Windows, i.e. a service that will run a configurable script at 06:30 every morning. But as for typical scripting languages for Windows, I sadly know nothing.

Comment: »Does it matter if my operating system is win 10 32 bit or 64 bit?«:  I assume that that is not a problem. You are interested in the contents of your databases and not the binary code that runs the database system.

Comment: You could try to ask three seperate questions: (1) how on Windows to execute a script at 06:30 every morning (2) which scripting language to use on Windows to access contents of your database and (3) ... whatever then still isn't clear. But you might get complaints that StackOverflow is for programming questions and not for which tool to use.